# Python scrape likes of every post in a certain profile

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I have this code

```
#IMPORT THESE PACKAGES
import requests
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
#OPTIONAL PACKAGE, BUY MAYBE NEEDED
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#THIS INITIALIZES THE DRIVER (AKA THE WEB BROWSER)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
#THIS PRETTY MUCH TELLS THE WEB BROWSER WHICH WEBSITE TO GO TO
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/giftopiia/')
#Username
Username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/h2').text
#Type
Type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/div').text
#NUMBER OF POSTS
Posts = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/ul/li[1]').text
#NUMBER OF FOLLOWERS
Followers = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/ul/li[2]').text
#NUMBER FOLLOWING
Following = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/ul/li[3]').text
#Number Likes
Likes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div/a').text
#PRINTS OUT THE DATA PULLED FROM ABOVE
print(Username)
print(Type)
print(Posts)
print(Followers)
print(Following)
print(Likes)
```

This code retrieves the username,type of account, number of posts, number of followers and people followed, and the number of likes of a certain post if I open it.
Now I want to just give it a URL of a profile, and I want it to go through all the posts and get the likes per each post, or an average likes per post. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

this ix the xpath to get the number of likes in a post.

```
//button[text()='Post']/ancestor::section/preceding-sibling::section[1]/descendant::span
```

Simply call it with `find_element_by_xpath` and then call the `.text` to get the number of likes on the post.